# Create object of class inherited from type provided by different object

Tags: c++, templates, runtime, instance

I have the following classes

```
class CommonStyle
{};

class Style1 : public CommonStyle
{};

class Style2 : public CommonStyle
{};

class Style3 : public CommonStyle
{};

template<typename T> class ZStyle : public T
{
};
```

I have object which can be type of Style1, Style2, Style3. 
How can I create object of ZStyle inherited from Style1 or Style2 or Style3 depend on provided object?

```
//pseudo-code
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 CommonStyle* obj1 = new Style1();
 CommonStyle* obj2 = new Style2();
 CommonStyle* obj3 = new Style3();

 ZStyle* zobj1 = create_object_inherited_from_style1(obj1);
 ZStyle* zobj2 = create_object_inherited_from_style2(obj2);
 ZStyle* zobj3 = create_object_inherited_from_style3(obj3);
}
```

Is it possible to avoid dynamic_cast?

Comment: You can't write `ZStyle* zobj1`, you have to spell the type out: `ZStyle<Foo>* zobj1`.

Comment: It is very unclear what you actual goal with this architecture is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yeah I had an answer that you should probably be using some kind of dependency injection, but looking back at the question I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: There is dependency for third-party library, which use some base Style object. There are inherited classes XpStyle, VistaStyle, etc. I need to override couple of methods like virtual draw and provide the consumer with my custom Style object. So the consumer will use my custom method and the rest of base class which I don't take.

Comment: You cannot use ZStyle without a template argument. So the last three statements should not compile. You may need to redesign your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I might be answering a different question, but it may be the solution to you problem.

The [virtual constructor idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.8) may be helpful.

You create a virtual method called **clone()** in the base class, which is overridden in descendant classes. Then, you write
    CommonStyle* zobj1 = obj1.clone();
    CommonStyle* zobj2 = obj2.clone();
    CommonStyle* zobj3 = obj3.clone();

This results in three objects with static type CommonStyle, but dynamic type depending on what object they were clone()'d from.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I can't modify base class CommonStyle, and it does not have clone functionality.

Comment: Just saw your reply - in this case, this answer indeed doesn't help.
However - if you want to create a runtime-dependent behaviour, you can't use compile-time techniques such as templates.

Comment: I can't see how templates can help here, can you lead me?

Comment: I don't think they can ("... you **can't** use compile-time techniques such as templates.")

Answer (score 0):

How about the following CRTP-like modification:

```
template<typename T> class ZStyle : public T
{
    ZStyle(T const &);
};

class CommonBase
{
    /* original CommonStyle in here */
    virtual CommonBase * z() const = 0;
}

template<typename T> class CommonStyle : public CommonBase
{
    virtual ZStyle<T> * z() const
    {
         return new ZStyle<T>(static_cast<T const&>(*this));
    }
};

class Style1 : public CommonStyle<Style1> { };
class Style2 : public CommonStyle<Style2> { };
class Style3 : public CommonStyle<Style3> { };
```

Usage:

```
CommonStyle* obj1 = new Style1();
ZStyle<Style1> * p = obj1.z();
```

Alternatively, you can make the return type of `z()` to be `CommonBase *` so you don't need to worry about the type dependence in the last line.